# Python packages nashpy and axelrod preventing pyinstaller from working

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I have a file `file.py` that builds a tkinter GUI with the following dependencies:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import nashpy as nash
import axelrod as axl
import numpy as np
import warnings
```

I'm trying to convert it to an `exe` file using pyinstaller, but it isn't working for two reasons, which I've narrowed down to the lines `import nashpy as nash` and `import axelrod as axl`.

When I try to convert `file.py` or the following `testnash.py`

```
# testnash.py
import nashpy as nash
inp = input("Press Enter")
```

using pyinstaller, it spits out some of the normal output I usually see with pyinstaller, but then towards the end, I get the following (truncated) error:

```
(...)
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    return super()._safe_import_hook(target_module_partname, source_module, target_attr_names, level, edge_attr)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1245, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 484, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    return super()._safe_import_hook(target_module_partname, source_module, target_attr_names, level, edge_attr)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1232, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 484, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    return super()._safe_import_hook(target_module_partname, source_module, target_attr_names, level, edge_attr)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1245, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 484, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    return super()._safe_import_hook(target_module_partname, source_module, target_attr_names, level, edge_attr)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1232, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 484, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    return super()._safe_import_hook(target_module_partname, source_module, target_attr_names, level, edge_attr)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1245, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 484, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    return super()._safe_import_hook(target_module_partname, source_module, target_attr_names, level, edge_attr)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1232, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 484, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    return super()._safe_import_hook(target_module_partname, source_module, target_attr_names, level, edge_attr)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1232, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 484, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 368, in _safe_import_hook
    excluded_imports = self._find_all_excluded_imports(source_module.identifier)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 356, in _find_all_excluded_imports
    excluded_imports.update(module_hook.excludedimports)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 316, in __getattr__
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 383, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 577, in importlib_load_source
    mod_loader.exec_module(mod)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-matplotlib.py", line 34, in <module>
    if compat.is_win and hookutils.check_requirement('matplotlib >= 3.7.0'):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 414, in check_requirement
    return parsed_requirement.specifier.contains(version, prereleases=True)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\packaging\specifiers.py", line 905, in contains
    item = Version(item)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 196, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I'm not sure what to make of this, however. I tried installing auto-py-to-exe and converting it that way, but I got the same output.

When I comment out `import nashpy as nash` and try to convert `file.py` with just `import axelrod as axl` there, pyinstaller seems to work and does create `file.exe`, but when I try to run it, I get this ModuleNotFoundError [image: this], even though when I run `file.py` in VSCode it runs with axelrod just fine.

I've seen [this page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4503) and [this page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs), which was linked on it, about making sure everything is packaged correctly. I tried some of the things listed there, but haven't had any luck. I've tried using `--onedir` instead of `--onefile`. I've tried reinstalling pyinstaller. I've tried running it in Command Prompt vs a conda environment.

I'm using pyinstaller 6.4.0 and Python 3.9.18. Do I need to try a different version of pyinstaller? If so, how do I know which one? Is my program doomed to be a py file forever?